# Creating a vector, that contains all even numbers

Tags: r

Using R, I need to create a vector and in all even numbers. The numbers displayed must be in ascending order.

Comment: `x <- 1:50; x[x %% 2 == 0]`

Comment: Let's say if it is descending order how do I do it?

Comment: `rev(x[x %% 2 == 0])`